# How to verifying requests from Slack pushed by event e.g app_mention?

Tags: node.js, slack, slack-api

If a request comes from an action or slash command (body: with flat JSON) the hash is calculated properly but if a request comes from slack event e.g member_joined_channel (body: with nested object and array in one property calculated hash is wrong. Does anyone have a similar situation? How should I stringify body with a nested object or it isn't a problem?

Sample body from the event that hash is calculated wrongly:

```
{
  token: 'Nl6QizISEmzAEGEyoU5dXgJb',
  team_id: 'TG5TF58AA',
  api_app_id: 'BOB32T802',
  event: {
    type: 'member_joined_channel',
    user: 'UMSFF5SAD',
    channel: 'CG6CF6D4D',
    channel_type: 'C',
    team: 'TG3CF32RS',
    event_ts: '1566978171.000500'
  },
  type: 'event_callback',
  event_id: 'EvMS6K8BV2',
  event_time: 1566978171,
  authed_users: [ 'UMSFF5SAD' ]
}
```

My code to verify slack requests:

```
    const { body, headers } = req

    const {
      'x-slack-request-timestamp': slackRequestTimestamp,
      'x-slack-signature': slackSignature
    } = headers

    const bodyString = qs.stringify(body, { format: 'RFC1738' })

    const dataToHash =
 `${Config.signingSecretVersion}:${slackRequestTimestamp}:${bodyString}`
    const hashedData = crypto
      .createHmac("sha256", Config.signingSecret)
      .update(dataToHash)
      .digest("hex")

    const calculatedSignatureToCompare =
      `${Config.signingSecretVersion}=${hashedData}`

    if (calculatedSignatureToCompare !== slackSignature) {
      return res.status(401).send("unauthorized")
    }

    next()
```

Comment: please add a tag to clarify which language you are using

Comment: @ErikKalkoken I am using nodejs so language is JavaScript